# file aren't copied to WEB-INF/

Tags: maven, war, pom.xml

When i run a clean install goals on maven, my spring-servlet.xml is not copied in my war. Well it's not exactly true, it copy it into MyApp.War/WEB-INF/Classes/spring-servlet.xml, i want it to be there :
MyApp.War/WEB-INF/

I found my problem come from a bad Pom.xml configuration, i tried severals things, but unsucessfull :(

pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <resources>

        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>

        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>


    </resources>



    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>${*}</delimiter><!-- to keep the default behavior -->
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter><!-- to add Ant-like tokens style -->
                </delimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Définit le répertoire source de la webapp à la racine du projet et 
            avec comme nom le nom de l'artifact -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>it-nouveauProjet</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <manifest>
                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                </manifest>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
                        <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                        <Implementation-Environment>${projet.environnement}</Implementation-Environment>
                        <buildNumber>${buildNumber}</buildNumber>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
                   </build>
```

My web.xml is copied right, i want the same thing for my spring-servlet.xml and other files which are in the webapp/WEB-INF/ folder, i though maven war plugin copy all files in webapp/WEB-INF/ to my root folder of my war.

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Fist i would suggest to use an up-to-date version of the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), cause the current version is 2.3.